# I am not quite sure how to use "will had", "had" and "had been"

Tags: tense, usage, past-tense, past-perfect

I am not quite sure how to use "will had", "had" and "had been" to make sentences.  All I know is...

> I will have eaten my breakfast by 2pm.
>
> I have finished my project already.
>
> I have been working on my assignment since last Monday.

But I'm not quite sure how to use "will had", "had", "had been"

Answer (score 2):

"will had" is incorrect.

"had" is the past tense or the past participle of "have". i.e. either
"I had a taco" or "I had played the game too long".  "played" could any verb.

The difference between "have been" and "had been" is that "have been" describes something you have done occasionally and might be ongoing:

"I have been to that restaurant many times."

Had been describes a specific past action, usually indicating something has changed:

"I had been to the restaurant before, but never with a large group."

Comment: @emeraldemon. The present perfect can  be used for single, regular, repeated or permanent states. It is not restricted to things that happen occasionally The past perfect does not necessarily indicate that something changed.

Answer (score 1):

*I have finished my project already.*  (It is now in a finished state).
*I have been working on my assignment since last Monday.* (I am still working on it now.)

*I had finished my project when my father got home.*  (It was in a finished state at that past time.)
*I had been working on my assignment since the previous Monday, seven days of hard work.* (I was still working on it on the seventh day, a time-point in the past.)

Past perfect forms place the situation mentioned in a time period that extended up to some past time-point.

Comment: With a bit of ingenuity, we can also project that "unfinished activity" into the future. *"By August the new cook will have been being introduced to her duties for several weeks"*. But that's the sort of thing you're more likely to find in "teaching" books telling us what forms are *possible* (i.e. - more of a "mention" than a "use").